# ExecuteUpdate in java successfully adds records to PostgreSQL but table will not update

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm currently adding data to a PostgreSQL database via `executeUpdate` based on input from the client side of a Spring Boot application. I'm adding a `comment`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `address`, and `username` to a Review table using the following code in a java method.

I pass the information in a method in a controller class using this line :

```
addReviewMethod.addReview( comment,  longitude,  latitude,  address,  username);
```

And this will pass the data to another java class and insert it into a table like so:

```
public void addReview(String comment, double longitude, double latitude, String address, String username) {

    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/arearatingpgdb",
            "postgres", "root");
         c.setAutoCommit(false);

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         int rs = stmt.executeUpdate( "INSERT INTO reviews VALUES (nextval('reviews_id_seq'::regclass), '" +comment +" '," +longitude+"," +latitude+", '"+address+"', '"+username+"');" );

         System.out.println("Successfully added: " +  comment + longitude + latitude + address + username);
        /* while ( rs.next() ) {
            Review  review = rs.getDouble("price");
            System.out.println();
            housePrices.add(price);
         }*/
         //rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         c.close();
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
}
```

I've included print debuggers in both the controller class and the class that executes the insert and they print the correct information that shows me everyting shold be working correctly.

The issue I'm having is when I review the contents of the table i.e. `select * from reviews` in pgAdmin4 the only rows in the table are the ones I've hardcoded in. Even more confusingly when I hardcode another row into the table via the query tool the id columns reflect that the rows have actually been added from the java side but they are not displaying in the table. For example I hard coded in 2 rows, then I tried to run the methods 4 times then I hard coded in another 2 rows and the database looks like this.

```
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
  6 | foo
  7 | bar
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to commit those changes.

so do `c.commit()` before `stmt.close()` or just change `c.setAutoCommit(false);` to `c.setAutoCommit(true);`

Comment: You answered first and that worked perfectly thank you x

Answer (score 0):

Connections in Java are auto-commit by default. In your code, you have deliberately setup your connection's auto commit to false. You can fix the code in two ways:

- Comment out below code segment

  c.setAutoCommit(false);
- Commit your changes before closing the statement

  c.commit();

Answer (score 0):

You've to add c.commit() just before closing your Connection object. Because this statement will flush your changes to the database permanently. setAutoCommit(false) changes the behaviour of implicit commit of transaction and the transaction needs to be explicitly committed by using commit().